# Crontab camera capture using python-opencv

Tags: python, opencv, cron

Here is my python program:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env/ python
  import cv
  capture1=cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
  cv.SetCaptureProperty(capture1,cv.CV_CAP_PROPER_FRAME_WIDTH,320)  
  cv.SetCaptureProperty(capture1,cv.CV_CAP_PROPER_FRAME_HEIGHT,240)
  while 1:
       cam1=cv.QueryFrame(capture1);
       cv.SaveImage("camera.jpg",cam1);
       cv.WaitKey(11)
       print 'Done!'
```

On crontab:

```
@reboot sudo python /home/program.py >/home/result.txt
```

But its not saving the image.Definitely I have done something wrong! I got the similar problem when I was reading image `cv2.imread("image.jpg")` but it was returning `None` so I added full path to the image `/home/image.jpg`.That problem was solved!.Is cron not getting camera feed? 
Thanx for help!

Comment: yes, try an absolute path like /home/camera.jpg. alse check the return value for cv.SaveImage(). last, but not least, the old cv api won't be supported in the future, so move over to cv2 in the long run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, make sure the application succeeds communicating with the camera:

```
import cv
capture1 = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
if not capture1 :
    print "!!! Failed to open a camera interface"
    # Ideally, exit the application.

cv.SetCaptureProperty(capture1,cv.CV_CAP_PROPER_FRAME_WIDTH,320)  
cv.SetCaptureProperty(capture1,cv.CV_CAP_PROPER_FRAME_HEIGHT,240)
```

Remember to test if the frame was successfully retrieved from the camera:

```
while 1:
     frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture1);
     if not frame:
         print "!!! Failed to retrieve frame"
         break

     # Right now, your code overwrites the same file at every iteration of the loop.
     # It might be better to add a BREAK at the end for testing purposes.
     cv.SaveImage("camera.jpg", frame);

     # There's no need to call WaitKey() if the image is not displayed on a window.
     #cv.WaitKey(11)    

     print 'Done!'
```

`SaveImage()` will fail when the application doesn't have permission to write files in the directory from where it was executed. Since **crontab** is responsible to call your application, I imagine that it does that from a directory where the user doesn't have the right permissions. If this is the case, I strongly suggest you to **feed `SaveImage()` with the full path to the file**.

Comment: @karlphilip thanx for your help ! :) Actually this is some part of my long code.It is just to show what I am doing .I have tested this program(on terminal).And I am getting output.My problem is running that program from cron.Cron is not connected to my webcams.That is why I am not getting any output.If you know linking cameras with cron ,please help me out!

Comment: In normal execution (from terminal),everything is  fine. I have these checks in my original code.

Comment: Is there a chance this is happening before the driver of the camera is loaded? Your first comment added important information to the question. It's clear that this is not an issue related to programming.

Comment: Yes this is the issue with cron.OK ! that might be a reason .I will add some delay in the program so the webcams drivers get loaded.Thank you  so much for help!

Comment: I added delay,but nothing happened ! :(

Comment: So the problem is solved partially! I tried coding with cv2. cv and cv2 both are capturing frames but they both are not not saving images,when program is executed through cron.However, I am happy that atleast  images are being captured.(I checked them by printing on text file).

Comment: Neither cv2.imwrite() nor cv.SaveImage() are saving images :(.

Comment: @karlphilip sorry I don't put all my code here.Actual code consist of cv.ShowImage().As I am doing coding on raspberry Pi so I typed small portion of code here.ShowImage made cron  stuck at that point.I commented that line.Now images are saving in the directory! :)

Comment: Well, consider clicking on the checkbox near my answer if you feel that it has helped you answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in  `cv.ShowImage` or `cv2.imshow`.When I commented this line everything worked fine! Previously the program got stuck at this this line.(while execution through `cron`).[That I was writing in my original program]